# How to get Button click from Fragments

Tags: java, android

I got a Fragment that need to take a buttonclick.

Problem is that the click it going to the MainActivity hosting all fragments and not to the Fragment itself.
I have tried Loging it and nothing shows in the logs when i click the button.

I will show u the entire onCreateView.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.server_settings, container, false);
    final Button loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addServerSettingsbtn);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            //were the magic won't happen.
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.server_settings, container,false);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem (I believe) is that you're returning an instance of the inflated view that doesn't have the onClick handler assigned.

Try this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.server_settings, container, false);
    final Button loginButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.addServerSettingsbtn);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            //were the magic won't happen.
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to return `view` instead of inflate again `server_setting`. inflate returns everytime a new object

Comment: Oh thanks you! Been on the problem for a good 4 hours (and same amount of beer)